# nested linear layouts with weights - how to space evenly on different size devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a vertical linear layout with many linear layouts (horizontal) that take up the left side of a a tablet

I get warnings about nesting weights if I use weights on the nested layouts

I also can't seem to get things to look consistent - I want them to take up 100% of the screen size

but on a small 5" screen not all the items are shown, and on a large 10" screen they only take up a 30% of the screen

What am suppose to do?

Here is what it looks like on a small tablet (notice the bottom items are cut off)
[image: 5" Version]

Here is what it looks like on a 10" tablet (notice it no longer takes up the full side)
[image: 10" Version]

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sidebar_linlay1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Address" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_streetnum_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_streetname_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="City" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_city"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Zip" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_zip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="number" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Email" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Type" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spin_status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

            </LinearLayout>



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/map_notes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:text="notes" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/but_ClientForm"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Open Contract" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/but_saveData"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Save Changes" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple suggestions:

- Use alternate layouts for different screen sizes.

You do this with *configuration qualifiers*.  Here is an example:  You have a default layout for small screens in `/res/layout` folder.  Now, if you want to have a different layout for a larger screen, you create a variation of your layout and put it in a different folder; for example `/res/layout-w600dp` contains layouts for devices with a minimum width of 600dp.

Refer to this page on Android Developers:

[Supporting Multiple Screens | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

- To see all the views on a smaller device, wrap your layout in a `ScrollView`

Then at least your users will be able to scroll to see all the views in your layout.

- To spread out views vertically on larger devices, use `Space` view with weights in between vertical views.

This is a trick I use to spread views out vertically on larger devices.  For example:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sidebar_linlay1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text_streetnum_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text_streetname_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="City" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text_city"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Zip" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text_zip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Type" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spin_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:padding="0dip"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/map_notes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text="notes" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/but_ClientForm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Open Contract" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/but_saveData"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save Changes" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

The Space views will expand so that the views are spread out evenly on the device.  This is not a magic bullet; you still have to look at how the view renders on larger screens and find out if it's spread out too much.  Sometimes I will use `Space`s with weight of 1 and at the very bottom, put a `Space` with a weight of 2 or 3.  On larger screens, this leaves some margin at the bottom so that the views don't look too spread out.

The nested weights warning is just to let you know that layouts having both horizontal and vertical weights may take longer to render.  Again, you have to determine what works for you.  I have had to resort to nested weights on some of my layouts, and I haven't had any unacceptable rendering delays.  But YMMV as always.